# Laravel Redirect Intended Defaulting to a Route Name

Tags: laravel

How do I return a redirect intended passing a route name instead of a path?

typically the method intended accepts a path for a default if the intended is not defined. I'd like to be able to pass a route name instead of a path. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

return redirect()->intended(\URL::route('admin.dashboard', [], false));

Comment: You could just use `route()` instead of `\URL::route()`